# EF: One-to-many relationship - querying for a subset of the data

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am trying to fetch a collection of entities from a one-to-many relationship as an IQueryable so I can filter the data down before fetching this from the database.

To make it clear, consider the following example:

I currently have an entity "User" which has a collection of Pictures:

```
public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures{ get; set; }
```

The Picture entity may or may not belong to a User, and hence, doesnt have the User property in its definition.

A user may have thousands of pictures, but I would like to select the first 10 for example, ordered by Picture.Id. Is there a way to do this?

Maybe something along the lines like:

```
IQueryable<ICollection<Picture>> pictures = context.Users.Where(u=>u.UserId == userId).Select(c => c.Pictures)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is to use the `OrderBy` and `Take` methods on the `Pictures` collection of the user. However, since you want to make sure that you only perform a single EntityFramework SQL query without loading the entire `Pictures` collection of a user, this needs to be expressed in a slightly more specific way.

**Query syntax**

```
var result = (from u in users
              where u.Id == userId
               from p in u.Pictures
               orderby p.Id
               select p).Take(10);
```

**Method syntax**

```
var result = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 2)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Pictures)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
    .Take(10);
```

Note the call to `SelectMany`. It's important. Basically this adds up all the `Pictures` collections of all the selected users into one list and continues the query on this flattened meta-list. In theory this sounds like a pretty big operation, but in this case there should only be one user with a specific ID, so it really just continues with the selected user's `Pictures` collection. The generated SQL is a single, fast query:

**Resulting SQL query** (for both of the above)

```
SELECT TOP (10)
[Extent1].[User_Id] AS [User_Id],
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Pictures] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[User_Id] IS NOT NULL) AND (2 = [Extent1].[User_Id])
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

Comment: Would this be data intensive? As in, would this fetch all the thousands of pictures, and then order and take the ones I want? Or would it be lazy, and select only the ones I request for, for example, the first 10 pictures

Comment: LINQ is lazy as much as possible. If this is to a collection of CLR objects or to an SQL database - yes, it's lazy! If it wasn't, LINQ2SQL would be useless. :) Actually, this LINQ expression won't get evaluated until you force it do become so - either tagging it with `.ToList()` or accessing it through an iterator block.

Comment: So if I use the first line, it would evaluate all the pictures? as in, context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userId).Pictures.OrderBy(p => p.Id).Take(10) is not lazy, while the second block of code (under LINQ is lazy?)

Comment: Oh - no - both are lazy! Just different ways of typing (basically) the same thing. It's just a matter of taste. :) A good read on LINQ and lazy loading: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/10/01/lazy-linq-and-enumerable-objects.aspx

Comment: ah, what got me confused was that context.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userId).Pictures returned an ICollection<Picture> so I thought it had already loaded the Pictures.

Comment: Ah, this is Entity Framework. I think this is a bit more complex when it comes to lazy loading to be honest. See this SO thread for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288552/entity-framework-lazy-loading-and-icollection If you want to optimize this for laziness I'd recommend fetching the Pictures property separate, from it's own entity collection, and applying the filters there.

Comment: Actually, I think the LINQ query is lazy evaluated - the return type of the second block is a IQueryable<Number>

Comment: I really can't say for sure as I can't test this on my own right now. I would recommend using SQL Profiler and inspect the query/queries sent when you execute this code.

Comment: Since the LINQ query gives back a IQueryable, I am pretty sure its lazily evaluated, while the first line is evaluated eagerly. Might be worth updating your answer ;)

Comment: I have thought about this the entire weekend and I got irritated by the fact that the method syntax didn't give me the same results. So I decided to figure out how to do it. See my edited answer for the exciting conclusion. :)